# How to use vue draggable with vuex properly?

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I'm new to vue and I'm trying to implement draggable features in my vue application. In this applications I'm using vuex, axios and [vuedraggable package](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next).

Here is my template and script screenshots

[image]

and here is script sections

[image]

I've no any idea where to specify  updateGlobalTodo method. Can I use patch method instead for put method to update?

and vuex script is here

[image]

and here is response data format

[image]

Comment: What is the thing you want to update bro?

Comment: I want to update order

Answer (score 0):

You can add change method to listen the change event of the draggable and set the update event there

> ```
> <div class="col-3">
>   <h3>Draggable 2</h3>
>   <draggable
>     class="dragArea list-group"
>     :list="list2"
>     group="people"
>     @change="updateOrderMethod"
>     item-key="name"
>   >
>     <template #item="{ element }">
>       <div class="list-group-item">
>         {{ element.name }}
>       </div>
>     </template>
>   </draggable>
> </div>
> ```

and add the update Vuex at the methods :

> methods: {
> updateOrderMethod: function(evt) {
>
> ```
>   window.console.log(evt); // inside evt variable you can get the item and the index order
>   this.updateGlobalTodo();
> }   }
> ```